# Adding a reference to a DLL, while keeping it a native DLL instead of an ActiveX Control

Tags: dll, com, visual-studio-2013

I'm forced to use a third-party COM component in an application, and I'm having issues adding the reference to my project.

I've added this DLL as a reference to a project before, but in the past it would link directly to the DLL, such that the "Path" in the reference's properties would be filesystem path where the DLL was installed (i.e. *not* relative to my solution's directory). However, now, when I add the reference, the "Path" is to my project's `obj` directory, "Embed Interop Types" is set to True, and it's listed as an ActiveX component (which is not correct).

Then, I stumbled upon [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx), which says:

> If you want to add a reference to a registered COM DLL that contains an internal manifest, unregister the DLL first. Otherwise, Visual Studio adds the assembly reference as an ActiveX Control instead of as a native DLL.

Well, there you have it. That's my exact problem. I need the native DLL, but I'm getting an ActiveX Control instead. So, I did as it suggested and unregistered the DLL. However, when I then try to add the reference, I get an error saying:

> A reference to ... could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

If I register the DLL again, I'm able to add it as a reference, but again, it's added as an ActiveX control. At this point, I don't know what else to do. Microsoft is very clear that I must unregister it before adding it as a reference, but then Visual Studio 2013 apparently won't let me add an unregistered DLL. Any one have any idea how to work around this?

*UPDATE*

So, apparently a recent update to this app made COM the only option (no directly using the DLL). The fact that it was added as ActiveX didn't mean anything. The problem turned out to be that this was a 32-bit library trying to run in 64-bits. I knew that was a potential problem, but switching the platform target to x86, still resulted in an error so I ended up chasing a red herring. Turns out IIS Express 8 runs natively as 64-bits even if the platform target of the site you're debugging is 32-bit. I had to go into Visual Studio options and uncheck the flag that tells IIS Express to run 64-bit (under "Web Projects") and then everything ran fine.

Comment: Do you use the DLL as a COM component or with DllImport?

Comment: If you're willing to give up "Embed Interop Types", you can manually use `TlbImp.exe`, which doesn't generate the WinForms wrapper for ActiveX (as opposed to `AxImp.exe`). You can then use ILMerge if you still want a single monolithic assembly.

Comment: Honestly, when it comes to this stuff, I'm pretty clueless. I *believe* it's being used as a COM component. How could I verify? Also, this DLL is part of an application and has to stay where it is. It won't work if it's brought into my project during build or rolled up into my project's DLL. It resides in a known location and the application it comes from must be installed on any server my project is deployed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since adding the registered DLL was pretty much a no-go, I focused instead on trying to figure out why Visual Studio wouldn't let me add it when it was unregistered. I mean, sure, I might get an error about it being an unregistered DLL once I tried to run the project, but it should at least let me add it as a reference, regardless.

I eventually stumbled upon `tlbimp.exe`, which according to Microsoft:

> The Type Library Importer converts the type definitions found within a COM type library into equivalent definitions in a common language runtime assembly. The output of Tlbimp.exe is a binary file (an assembly) that contains runtime metadata for the types defined within the original type library.

Okay. Well anyways, I opened a Visual Studio Developer Prompt (regular `cmd` doesn't have `tlbimp.exe` on the path), and ran my DLL through it. It created a new DLL, which I *was* able to add as a reference, and it satisfied my project dependencies. However, I haven't tested it just yet to make sure everything still works as it should once this thing is running, so I'll update with what I find there.

**UPDATE**

Yeah, so this doesn't work either. I get the same error once it's running saying that the class is not registered. Only now, I can't register this DLL because `tlbimp.exe` removes the entry-point.

Comment: Isn't it what I suggested in the comment to your question?

Comment: Somewhat, but this is *not* an ActiveX control. It's being incorrectly added to the project as one. That's the problem. Regardless, it doesn't work. See my update.

Comment: That's shockingly bad advice in that MSDN article.  Do *not* unregister it, that just makes sure that you can't debug your code.  Do not panic when you see it is an ActiveX control, that just creates a class derived from AxHost, allowing you to put the control on a Winforms form.  You still have the interop library that allows you to use it directly.  You'll have to fix the damage you did, re-running the installer is best.  Or make sure you re-register the COM server by running Regsvr32.exe from an elevated command prompt.  Passing the name of the original DLL, not the interop library.

Comment: @HansPassant: thank you for your comment. It came after I had already solved this, but you provided a clear description of the issue that would have helped me if i hadnt already got there myself. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't understand this: *I can't register this DLL because tlbimp.exe removes the entry-point.* Are you trying to do regsvr32 on the  interop assembly produced by tlbimp, rather than on the original unmanaged DLL?